# To what is the value of Qantas travel credit linked?

Tags: international-travel, refunds, covid-19, qantas

We're in South Africa and had booked flights with Qantas to see family in Sydney during May. With the current conditions it is necessary to cancel the flights and receive travel credit or ask for a refund.
Does anyone know how the travel credit is "linked" to the value of the flight? 
Is it in Australian Dollars, South African Rands or points?
What would happen to the travel credit if the Rand weakens against the AUS dollar?

Comment: Airlines around the world are in deep trouble. There's no telling when flights will resume, or even if the airline will survive to resume them. If you have the option of a refund, protect your money and take it.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass, I agree with airlines being in deep trouble. We bought the tickets on a sale, so there is a significant fee (almost a third of the normal ticket price) for a refund in our case. We are therefore grateful for the option of travel credit. We are a family of five, (the youngest being an infant until August) so it does become a bit costly. If we take the travel credit we must use it by January 2021. Our visas for Australia are valid until March 2021.

Comment: Then it seems your original question is somewhat irrelevant. You have the choice of leaving the money with Qantas and it buys whatever it buys later in the year, which could be the flights you wanted, or it could be nothing, or taking two-thirds of it back now. Only you can decide what risk you're willing to take.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass, yes only we can decide. However, if we knew what the travel credit's value was linked to, we could make a more informative decision. If it is linked to the Rand, then that's bad as the Rand is currently spiralling. If it is linked to the Australian Dollar, then it is a better prospect.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's of historical value only and can no longer be answered accurately.